# shift count overflow when doing 1<<40

Tags: c++, c++11

I am puzzled on the following code behavior as to left shift: the intent is to define a variable terabytes, `TB = 1024*1024*1024*1024`, which would be `2**40` or `1<<40`. What is it complaining:

```
warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
    uint64_t TB = 1<<40;
                   ^ ~~
1 warning generated.
```

This is compiled on Mac (10.13.1), with clang-900.0.38, -std=c++11.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    uint64_t TB = 1<<40;
    std::cout << "TB = " << TB << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `1`? How wide is that type on your system?

Comment: What did the warning say?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this code :

`1ULL << 40`

Constants need a qualified type if you want something other than default.

Comment: Or using the macro to match types, `UINT64_C(1) << 40`.